# SQL: Start Date > 1 October Previous Year

Tags: sql

I'm building a query which only triggers if the start date is greater than 1 October Previous Year.

I imagine its something similar to using DATEADD below, but i'm not sure what to use instead of GETDATE. Thanks

`WHERE Start_Date > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())`

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

*If* you're using SQL Server, you could use `DATEFROMPARTS`:

```sql
WHERE Start_Date > DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,10,1)
```

*Note* that this will return the *prior* year regardless of when in the year is it. So, for example, even on `2021-12-31` the date `2020-10-01` would be returned from the expression.